# Referring to an alias instead of repeating the calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT   [outer].*,
         (total_pain_patients / NULLIF ((SELECT Sum(total_pain_patients)
             FROM   [topplansperprovider]
             WHERE  [outer].[INDEX_IMSID] = [INDEX_IMSID]
             AND plan_rank BETWEEN 1 AND 10), 0)) * 100 AS PercentOf,
         pm.*,
         percentof * pm.score
FROM     [topplansperprovider] AS [outer]
left JOIN [payer Mapping] pm
on lower([outer].Plan_Name_OR_Payment_Type)=lower(pm.[ims payer name])
WHERE    INDEX_IMSID = '1753841'
ORDER BY 6 ASC
```

My problem is with selecting this:

```
percentof * pm.score
```

Since `percentof` is the alias of a derived column, I don't know how to use it in other columns.

1. How do I select `percentof * pm.score`?
2. If that is too difficult, how can I just add `percentof` as a permanent column to my table?

Comment: Not sure what the questions is. You ask how to select something. But the query you posted already contains it!

Comment: @usr I've re-worded the question because it wasn't accurately describing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use an alias like that, you will have to wrap the query in another select:

```
select x.*, x.percentof*x.pm.score newvalue
from
(
    SELECT   [outer].*,
             (total_pain_patients / NULLIF ((SELECT Sum(total_pain_patients)
                                             FROM   [topplansperprovider]
                                             WHERE  [outer].[INDEX_IMSID] = [INDEX_IMSID]
                                                    AND plan_rank BETWEEN 1 AND 10), 0)) * 100 PercentOf,
             pm.*
    FROM     [topplansperprovider] AS [outer]
    left JOIN [payer Mapping] pm
        on lower([outer].Plan_Name_OR_Payment_Type)=lower(pm.[ims payer name])
) x
WHERE    x.INDEX_IMSID = '1753841'
ORDER BY 6 ASC
```

The column alias that you are calculating `percentof` is not available for use in another column, unless is it used in a sub-query.

Answer (score 3):

Create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.whatever
AS 
    SELECT 
      t.*, -- NAME THESE COLUMNS!!!
      PercentOf = (t.total_pain_patients / NULLIF ((SELECT Sum(t2.total_pain_patients)
         FROM   dbo.[topplansperprovider] AS t2
         WHERE  t2.[INDEX_IMSID] = t.[INDEX_IMSID]
         AND t2.plan_rank BETWEEN 1 AND 10), 0)) * 100,
      pm.* -- NAME THESE COLUMNS!!!
  FROM dbo.[topplansperprovider] AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[payer Mapping] AS pm
  ON LOWER(t.Plan_Name_OR_Payment_Type) = LOWER(pm.[ims payer name])
  WHERE t.INDEX_IMSID = '1753841';
GO
```

Now your query can be:

```
SELECT *, [something] = PercentOf * score -- NAME THIS ALIAS!
  FROM dbo.whatever
  ORDER BY 6 ASC; -- NAME THIS COLUMN!!!
```

However, please *stop* using lazy `SELECT *` syntax, especially with a view:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

And please *stop* using `ORDER BY [ordinal]`:

- [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

These are both bad habits that will cause you pain eventually.

Comment: Aaron, it seems like they're causing *you* pain right now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

While not the best answer you can create a view to have a "permanent" column in a view.